# is it okay to use `useDispatch` inside a function or a class?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

is it okay to use `useDispatch` hook inside a `function` or a `class`? I am not talking about functional or class components. I want to dispatch a state change from function/class.

```js
// Example: utils.ts

export function foo(){
  const bar = getBar();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  dispatch(addBar(bar))
}
```

Comment: It may help you to delegate the work of "getting bar" to the action creator `addBar`. So you would still use `dispatch(addBar());` in the component, but pass any arguments required for getting bar to `addBar()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, things that begin with `use` are hooks and can only be used in function components.

If you want access to dispatch from a function, do one of

- write the function as a thunk
- pass dispatch in as an argument
- import your store and call `store.dispatch`

Comment: `store.dispatch` is a good option for my case. But, what about using a custom hook (not related to redux). Suppose I have a hook `useBar()` and I want to do `const bar = useBar()` inside that `foo()` function. ig your suggested 2nd option would work... but how can I do it like we did `store.dispatch`? It sounds more convenient. Is it possible?

Comment: Hooks are hooks because at one point down the line they call one of the React hooks like useState, useEffect, useMemo or useRef. All of those can only be called within a React component.
If your custom never called any of those, it would not have required to be a hook in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is correct!!
Just to add, this syntax might help for beginners if you want to do some async calls or get state.

Requisite -  Connect should be wrapped in root component.

```
store.dispatch(doSomething())

export function doSomething() {
    return async (dispatch, getState, { client }) => { //your code } }
```